# Store number of molecules and elements from a compound(input) in a dictionary

Tags: python

I am creating a program in python to take a chemical compound as an input and return the atoms and its number in a dictionary. Most of the work has been done but i cant seem to code how to add to to the number number of atoms if the element is repeated. For example CH3COOH (Acetic acid).

this is the code

```
element = input("Enter an element: ")
count = {}
string = "";
x = 0
something = "";
something_number = 0
if "(" in  element: 
    something = element[element.index("(")+1 : element.index(")")];
    something_number = int(element[element.index(")")+1])
for i in element:
    try:
        if string in something: 
            count[string] = int(i) * something_number
            string = "";
            x += 1;
        else:
            count[string] = int(i);
            string = "";
            x += 1;
            
    except ValueError:
        if i != "(" and i!= ")":
            string += i;
        else:
            pass
        try:
            if element[element.index(i)+1] == element[element.index(i)+1].upper() and element[element.index(i)+1] not in "123456789":
                if string in something: 
                    count[string] = something_number
                    string = "";
                    x += 1;
                else:
                    count[string] = 1
                    string = "";
                    x += 1;
        except IndexError:
            if string in something: 
                    count[string] = something_number
                    string = "";
                    x += 1;
            else:
                count[string] = 1
                string = "";
                x += 1;
    except:
        print("error")
try:
    for i in enumerate(count):
        if i[1] == "":
            del count[i[1]]
except RuntimeError:
    pass


print(count);
```

Comment: You definitely don't need all those semicolons. Apart from that, try to be clearer in explaining your problem. Which cases have you tried? What results did they give you? What results would you have liked instead?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are looking for a way to update your dictionary, when you encounter the element a second time. The easiest way, is probably to use `get` on the dictionary with default value 0. E.g. `count["C"] = count.get("C", 0) + 1` will set the value for "C" to 1 if it doesn't exist yet in the dictionary and increase it by one if it does.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: You execute a lot of your actual code as part of exception handling for ValueError, which is really bad practice. Use `i.isdigit()`to determine whether i can be converted to an int and write the code in the else branch rather than under the `except ValueError`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but there are built-in that do what you are looking for. Check counter which is similar to a dictionary,

You need to first expand the molecule

```py
from collections import Counter

def expand_molecule(molecule):
    expand = ""
    for num, val in enumerate(molecule):
        if val.isnumeric():
            expand +=  molecule[num-1]*int(val)
        else:
            expand += val
    return expand

molecule_expand = expand_molecule("CH3COOH")
molecule = Counter(molecule_expand)
print(molecule)
```

the output is

```
Counter({'H': 5, 'C': 2, 'O': 2})
```